# CassUI server not starting

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to get my hands-on cassui. Given Cassandra server URL and port number as mycassandraserver:9160
When I try to see whether server is running or not browser is giving error as -

**Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to mycassandraserver.com:9160**

Any idea? What should I do?

Comment: what do u mean by CassUI?? 9160 is the rpc default port

Comment: CassUI is the web based interface over cassandra. (no-sql database)

Comment: can you ping that port?

Comment: Yes.. Correct! I already placed war under tomcat/webapps

Comment: Rather first step of creating a new server under CassUI is already done. Now next step is to run it by typing <server_name>:9160 (mycassandraserver:9160) in browser. This is where I am getting error...

Comment: why dont you try with mycassandraserver:<tomcat-port>/cassui/

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded CassUI, deployed to my local webserver and got this to work:

> [image: CassUI admin page]

Port 9160 is the RPC port for Cassandra, so you won't be able to navigate to that port from a web browser.  Make sure that you navigate to the server:port of your ***webserver***, and then you should be able to add your Cassandra server.

> Rather first step of creating a new server under CassUI is already
>   done.

I assume that you are referring to the steps listed here: https://code.google.com/p/cassui/
I'll try to keep that in mind with my answers below.

> Now next step is to run it by typing :9160
>   (mycassandraserver:9160) in browser. This is where I am getting
>   error...

This is the step that you are mis-interpreting.  You are getting an error because you are NEVER going to be able to browse to your Cassandra server from a web browser on port 9160.

> 3- Add Cassandra server's IP address (and port if not 9160 with the
>   separator being a colon) for example 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.1:9160 or
>   mycassandraserver.com:9160

This is describing how you have to define your Cassandra server to CassUI when you click "New Server."  Based on what you have said, you should have already done this.

> 4- Start browsing through the keyspaces and individual column family.

"Browsing" in this case means that you click on the name of your server in the CassUI server list, and it shows you something similar to my screenshot below:

> [image]

Notice that the URL in my browser is not my Cassandra server and port number.

Comment: Thanks! I got that screen you casted above. But I want to access cassandra URL. Can you please elaborate more on how do I navigate to server:port of webserver... I am new to this environment so don't know much @ this... Thanks in advance!

Comment: YEs.. correct.. I did that and I am referring to same link.. But the notifications which are there after Keyspaces, I am unable to see a single one also.. Even I am not able to give name to my cluster.. Not able write anything infront of Server and Port.